# Azure table storage to trigger mobile notification

Tags: azure, push-notification, azure-storage, azure-mobile-services

I have an Azure-hosted API that accepts logging/tracing data from multiple customer applications for the purpose of identifying/aggregating issues before the customer raises them in a support call. The API writes logging data to Azure Table storage. This works great with powerbi.com etc. for regular proactive monitoring, however...

As a "2.0" enhancement, I want to set up mobile notifications when defined conditions are met (e.g. 2+ table records created with a "severity" attribute = 1 within the space of 60 minutes, maybe where "ProjectType" = Mine). I don't want to send notifications on each entry to the table but rather trigger a notification on aggregated entries within a rolling time frame.

Are there any Azures service that provides this without having to create a custom cron job querying table storage every few minutes/hour (and therefore increasing PAYG costs). And would necessitate moving away from Azure Table Storage to Azure SQL?

Answer (score 2):

I would investigate [Azure Stream Analytics](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/stream-analytics-introduction/) and see if that meets your needs.  It provides a sql-like query dialect, including things like tumbling windows (how often an event occurred within a given time frame).  Here's a nice [example](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/stream-analytics-get-started/).

A lower tech solution would be running a [WebJob](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/web-sites-create-web-jobs/#CreateScheduled) within an App Service.  You could run it on a free tier in order to keep cost down if that is a concern.  Sql Server would give you more flexibility in your queries compared to table storage.